# How do I find the position of an element in raphael?

Tags: javascript, raphael

I am using raphael to animate a ball and need to find out the position after stopping the animation, here is the code I have:

```
ball.stop();
console.log(ball.attrs.transform);
// t399.6625490203161,180r180
```

how do I convert this string into the x,y position of the ball?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use [`Element.getBBox`](http://raphaeljs.com/reference.html#Element.getBBox) for this:

```
var x = ball.getBBox().x;
var y = ball.getBBox().y;
var r = ball.getBBox().height / 2;
console.log(x, y, r);
```

---

*But beware*:

The coordinates (`element.getBBox().x`, `element.getBBox().y`) will refer to the upper left corner of the bounding box.
If the ball is a circle, that point will not even be contained in the circle and it might be more sensible to work with the coordinates of the center.

Given the bounding box `bbox`, to those would be

```
var x = bbox.x + bbox.width / 2,
    y = bbox.y + bbox.height / 2;
```

Comment: Spot on.  One caveat: the coordinates (element.getBBox().x, element.getBBox().y) will refer to the upper left corner of the bounding box.  If the ball is a circle, that point will not even be contained in the circle and it might be more sensible to work with the coordinates of the center.  Given the bounding box `bbox`, to those would be `x = bbox.x + bbox.width / 2`, `y = bbox.y + bbox.height / 2`.

Comment: @KevinNielsen, Very good addition thanks, I hope you don't mind if I  copy your comment into the answer, as it is very important!

Comment: absolutely.  I like the way you prefaced it with "But beware" =)  Cheers!

Comment: Hehe, I had to look up caveat :)